# Trouble returning reference

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine

I have been looking for the past couple of days and haven't had any joy. What I'm trying to do is dynamically produce a handle to an object and return it. I deconstructed a unity dll that I the project for when I reformatted and I'm having trouble getting it working again.

```
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [Serializable]
    internal sealed class ApplyCustomCosmectic : GenericGenerator<WWW>
    {
        internal PlayerScript self_1412;

        public ApplyCustomCosmetic(PlayerScript self_)
        {
            this.self_1412= self_;
        }

        public override IEnumerator<WWW> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new PlayerScript.ApplyCustomCosmetic.(this.self_1412);
        }
    }
}
```

The errors is spawned from the final line

```
PlayerScript.ApplyCustomCosmetic.(this.self_2175)
```

which works in the original dll however when I try to recompile with additions it throws an error. What is the best way to return this as a constructed object? ie. A new object of self

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace `PlayerScript.ApplyCustomCosmetic.(...` with `PlayerScript.ApplyCustomCosmetic(...`